# Entity Framework 6.4 missing migrate.exe

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I might just be completely out of date but I updated EF to 6.4 using nuget and I don't see migrate.exe in the tools folder anymore. Is there a change to run migrations? Or do I need to install another package for it? Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: As of EF6: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/migrate-exe

You can also use the package manager console to scaffold code first migrations: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links! I was there but did not scroll towards the bottom. Didn't realize they updated from migrate.exe to ef6.exe.

Answer (score 19):

For those who are as confused as I was, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/migrate-exe) from Microsoft is out of date. It looks like they change migrate.exe to ef6.exe starting from EF 6.3 as per [Nuget Github page](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/pull/7711).

Comment: It would be nice if they could open source their documentation so we all can fix documentation issues like this.

Comment: @Jason
The documentation is open-source, you can add an issue or even make a PR.

Note that this specific issue is already present : https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/1740